# CLLocation get only coordinates

Tags: arrays, swift, cllocation, polyline, cllocationcoordinate2d

I need to get an CLLocation array with only the coordinates, like this:

```
var locations = [CLLocation(latitude: 38.5, longitude: -120.2),
        CLLocation(latitude: 40.7000, longitude: -120.95000),
        CLLocation(latitude: 43.25200, longitude: -126.453000)]
```

I am currently saving every location like so:

```
var locationArray: [CLLocation] = []
```

In the didUpdateLocations:

```
locationArray.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)
```

But what i am always getting is something like this:

> [<-122.02684687,+37.32956209> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/9/14, 2:12:49 PM Central European Summer Time, <-122.02685248,+37.32959580> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/9/14, 2:12:49 PM Central European Summer Time, <-122.02685221,+37.32963096> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/9/14, 2:12:49 PM Central European Summer Time, <-122.02685460,+37.32966692> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/9/14, 2:12:49 PM Central European Summer Time

I tried converting it to an CLLocationCoordinate2D, but i always get the full location array and never the example above. I also tried something like this:

```
for (index,element) in enumerate(locationArray) {

        var cllocation = CLLocation(latitude: element.coordinate.longitude, longitude: element.coordinate.latitude)

        coordinatesArray.append(cllocation)

    }
```

But that also returns the full location array. What i am doing wrong? How can i create a CLLocation array with only the coordinates? If you can point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var locationArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
locationArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ..., longitude: ...))
```

`CLLocation` contains all the other stuff like `course`, `altitude`, accuracy...

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` just contains latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate threw the CLLocationCoordinate2D array and convert it to CLLocation. CLLocation has an appropriate init method ([- (instancetype)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude
                       longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithLatitude:longitude:).